# Array Manipulation: merge objects [ES6]

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

So i've been struggling for a few hours now. Here's what I'm trying to do.

I have an array of objects:

```
initArr = [
  {id: 5, time: 100, download: true},
  {id: 2, time: 50, download: false},
  {id: 3, time: 1000, download: true},
  {id: 5, time: 50, download: true},
  {id: 5, time: 550, download: false},
  {id: 2, time: 1500, download: true}
]
```

some objects have the same `id`, I want to merge them together.
- but when merging i want to sum the `time` value of both merged object .
- if one of the two merged objects has `download: false`, the merged object should have `false`, otherwise `true`.

Here's what I have so far (I did not start yet even considering the download key):

```
const mergedArr= [];

initArr.map(obj => obj['id'])
     .map((id, i, arr) => {
        if (arr.indexOf(id) === i) {
            mergedArr.push(initArr[i]);
        } else { 
          const mergeIndex = mergedArr.map( x => x.id).indexOf(id);
          mergedArr[mergeIndex].playTime +=initArr[arr.indexOf(id)].playTime;
        }
    return mergedArr
});
```

I'd love so inputs or hints :)

Comment: Is preserving the order important?

Comment: yes ! I should have mentioned that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reduce the array to a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) by the object's `id`, and then convert back to array using `Map.values()` and `Array.from()` (or by spreading into an array).

Note: in this case using Map as an accumulator is better than using an object, since the `id` property is numeric. In ES6 objects usually maintain the order of insertion, unless the properties are numeric. When an object with numeric property keys is convert to an array, the numeric properties come first, and they are ordered by their value. On the other hand, a Map always maintains the order of insertion.

```js
const initArr = [
  {id: 5, time: 100, download: true},
  {id: 2, time: 50, download: false},
  {id: 3, time: 1000, download: true},
  {id: 5, time: 50, download: true},
  {id: 5, time: 550, download: false},
  {id: 2, time: 1500, download: true}
]

const result = Array.from(initArr.reduce((r, o) => {
  if(!r.has(o.id)) r.set(o.id, { ...o });
  else {
    const current = r.get(o.id);
    current.time += o.time;
    current.download = current.download && o.download
  }
  
  return r;
}, new Map).values());

console.log(result);
```

Comment: +1 thanks !! With the order being important in my case, this solution is very helpful.
I'm not sure I quite understand it completely yet. I mean I get the reduce part. I've never used new Map though. I'll try to read on that. thanks again

Comment: You're welcome :) I'll add a link to info about Map as well.

Answer (score 2):

You could [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the array. Create an accumulator object with each `id` as key and the merged object as value. If the `id` already exists, update `time` and `download` with current object. Else, add the current `id` as key and set a copy of the current object as it's value. Then use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to get an array of values from this accumulator object.

```js
const initArr = [
  { id: 5, time: 100, download: true },
  { id: 2, time: 50, download: false },
  { id: 3, time: 1000, download: true },
  { id: 5, time: 50, download: true },
  { id: 5, time: 550, download: false },
  { id: 2, time: 1500, download: true }
]

const merged = initArr.reduce((acc, o) => {
  if (acc[o.id]) {
    acc[o.id].time += o.time;
    acc[o.id].download = acc[o.id].download && o.download;
  } else
    acc[o.id] = { ...o };

  return acc;
}, {})

console.log(Object.values(merged))
```

Comment: This case is not fit for an object accumulator, since the ids are numeric. You can see that the order has changed (id: 2 is the 1st item).

Comment: Can't you just use `r[o.id] = o` ?

Comment: @Kobe If not cloned, when `r[o.id].time += o.time` is done, it will mutate the original array's object

Comment: @OriDrori Why would an object not fit here? It works as well as an array or a `Map`. Order in the output is hardly relevant.

Comment: @Bergi - it might, and it might not. If it does, don't use an object.

Comment: @OriDrori …or just sort the values in the end by the order that you want.

Comment: Unless the order that you want is the original one :)

Comment: I should have specified indeed that the order matter here ! but thanks a lot for the detailed explanation !

Answer (score 1):

Try this, supports download option as well

```
const arr = [
  {id: 5, time: 100, download: true},
  {id: 2, time: 50, download: false},
  {id: 3, time: 1000, download: true},
  {id: 5, time: 50, download: true},
  {id: 5, time: 550, download: false},
  {id: 2, time: 1500, download: true}
]

const result = arr.reduce((res, obj) => {
    const found = res.find(t => t.id === obj.id);

    if(found){
        found.time += obj.time;
        found.download = found.download && obj.download;    
    } else {
        res.push(obj);
    }
    return res;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use reduce to:

- check if the array has the item with the ID on each loop
- if it does, add the time

else

- push the object

```js
const arr = [
  {id: 5, time: 100, download: true},
  {id: 2, time: 50, download: false},
  {id: 3, time: 1000, download: true},
  {id: 5, time: 50, download: true},
  {id: 5, time: 550, download: false},
  {id: 2, time: 1500, download: true}
]

console.log(arr.reduce((a, o) => {
  const i = a.findIndex(({id}) => id === o.id)
  i + 1 ? a[i].time += o.time : a.push(o)
  return a
}, []))
```

Answer (score 0):

One more `reduce` solution:

```js
const initArr = [
  {id: 5, time: 100, download: true},
  {id: 2, time: 50, download: false},
  {id: 3, time: 1000, download: true},
  {id: 5, time: 50, download: true},
  {id: 5, time: 550, download: false},
  {id: 2, time: 1500, download: true}
]

const merged = initArr.reduce((a,c) => {
    const found = a.find(x => x.id === c.id);
    if (found) {
        found.time += c.time;
        found.download = found.download && c.download;
        return a;
    }
    return [...a, {...c}];
}, []);

console.log(merged);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        function manipulation(initArr){
            var resultArray = [];
            var arrMap = new Map();
            var currIndex = 0;
            initArr.forEach(function(item, index){
                if(arrMap.has(item.id)){
                    var existingItem = resultArray[arrMap.get(item.id)];
                    existingItem.time = item.time+existingItem.time;
                    if(existingItem.download && !item.download){
                        existingItem.download = false;
                    }
                }else{
                    arrMap.set(item.id, currIndex);
                    resultArray.push(item);
                    currIndex++;
                }
            })
            return resultArray;
        }
```